# Selecting rows that return a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like to use a GridView in my web application, however I need to use it pragmatically.

I need to populate my grid view with data from access database (done already using DataTable) and then let the user select a row from the table. If the row is selected, the user can click a button that will redirect him/her to a new web page that will allow him/her to edit data from the database. I want to achieve this by writing code  (well, i click and drag the gridView control and then write code for it).

After researching I finally managed to populate my GridView using DataTable, however I am unable to find a solution that would make each row selectable and return a specific value (e.g. string from Name column).

Could someone point me in the right direction, please? :) 
I would like to be able to use it, in a similar way like JTable in Java.

This is project for my coursework. I do not want to use any sort of wizards, as this will result in reduced marks. I could get away with using ListBox but I would like to go a bit further and learn something new.

This is my current code (contains only sample data and is not connected to a database).

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("DOB");

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dt.Rows.Add(new Object[] { 1, "Smith" });

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

EDIT:

I managed to find very simple way of doing what I need to do. This method changes my initial idea, however this will make my web app more user friendly and faster to use :) This is my solution:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Name");
                dt.Columns.Add("DOB");

                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dt.Rows.Add(new Object[] { 1, "Smith" });
                //Generate buttons for each row 
                GridView1.AutoGenerateSelectButton = true;
                //string array that acts as a key for which values to be return once an even occurs 
                string[] key = { "Name" };
                GridView1.DataKeyNames = key; 

                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            { 
//simple label to check if the program returns correct value 
Label2.Text = GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString();

            }
```

I hope this helps someone :) 
Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a link button to your grid as a template field and set the link URL at run time from your object model.
You will have all your links bounded with the correct URL, once clicked (call javascript function) it will navigate the user to the specified URL with the correct row / object Id.

**HTML**

```
<asp:Grid id="gridId" OnRowDataBound="grdId_RowDataBound">
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkId" Text='<%#Eval("Your Object Property")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</asp:grid>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void grdId_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkId");
//Get your URL which could be http://domain/page?Id=currentRowId
lnk.OnClientClick = "return navigate('"URL');"
}
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function navigate(url)
{
window.location.href = url;
}
```